# Unable to insert into the table

Tags: sql

[image]

```
declare @Sampledate table (SampleDate datetime)

insert into @Sampledate
    select 
        '04/07/2018 18:18:29'
```

I get an error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

AS of getting the data like this from the browser to SQL. How to resolve it?

Please try inserting in the same manner. Date in one row and time in another row. Need a quick response, please.

Comment: Can you explain how it comes from a browser as line break?
Also you have to handle it there to avoid line break

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to remove the line feed or carrier return if you insist on putting date and time on two lines.

```
declare @sampledate table (sampledate datetime)
insert into @sampledate select REPLACE('04/07/2018 
18:18:29',CHAR(10),'')
```

OR

```
declare @sampledate table (sampledate datetime)
insert into @sampledate select REPLACE(REPLACE('04/07/2018 
18:18:29',CHAR(10),''),CHAR(13),'')
```

Comment: Same scenario. Can you apply the logic in this date.      315000-02-1|04/07/2018 13:18:29|04/07/2018 18:18:29|133060 ..            break the date and time into 2 rows. Any idea on this, Here break any one date and try to insert it will throw an error. conversion failed to datetime.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for **SQL Server** - you have two options:

**Option 1**: use the **ISO-8601** date format in your string literal to be independent of the language/regional settings in your SQL Server instance - this is recommended to be used always - it just helps avoid trouble:

```
INSERT INTO @Sampledate(SampleDate)
    SELECT '2018-04-07T18:18:29'
```

This is a date in `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` format - it will always work, regardless of your settings in SQL Server - while many other formats will work sometimes, but not other times.

**Option 2**: use the `DATETIME2(n)` datatype (instead of `DATETIME`) which is a lot less "finicky" about the string literal format being inserted.

```
DECLARE @Sampledate TABLE (SampleDate DATETIME2(0));

INSERT INTO @Sampledate(SampleDate)
    SELECT
        '04/07/2018 18:18:29'
```

This *may* work - again, it's *less finicky*, but the string literal is still dependent on your language/regional settings - it *might* work - or not. Using option #1 is definitely your safer bet - but also, I'd recommend using `DATETIME2(n)` over `DATETIME` (as of SQL Server **2008**), too - it's just the better datatype (uses less space, offer a larger date range, less tricky about inserting values into - only benefits, really!)

Comment: in the select statement keep the date in one row and time in another row   and then try to insert it.here you are using the datetime in one line. try with two lines. i have attached a sample image in my question. try it out

Comment: @DanielStephen: that'll **never work** since you're putting a linebreak/carriage return into your string literal - that can never be successfully converted to a date/time.....

Comment: I am not adding line break in the code. when it comes from browser it comes like that. In sql trace also line break is happening.